# Stackdriver Log not showing in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, error-logging

I am writing a Google web app and when debugging I usually find logs from the stackdriver in the list of executions. But now it only shows the failed execution but no log.
I am a beginner at this, so I might have missed something. Or has anything changed?!
I follow what this guide says: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#stackdriver_logging

Screenshot of my executions list in google apps script panel[image]

Answer (score 1):

If no logs show after clicking each execution, you can

- Wait upto a hour and  refresh
- [Switch over to standard Google cloud project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project) and use View > Stackdriver logging

You need to clear the filter "Status:Failed or Cancelled" on top left to show other executions.

Answer (score 0):

Since today, my published/deployed apps script web apps have stopped working. I believe this may be a service outage issue. All triggers associated with the web apps are also failing. The script editor won't even load for those particular applications. I don't think this has anything to do with you and your application, I think this is a system issue.

I've submitted a bug here: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/166010550

I hope it is resolved soon..